# Add feature symbology in pyQgis

Tags: qgis

While adding a polygon feature in QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera, the representation symbology of that particular feature(which is in-progress) appears to be "filled" until the completion(rightclick)  of digitization, eventhough that layer symbology is given as 'Outline: Simple line' as shown in attached screenshot[image: Adding new feature]. How to fix this?

Comment: before commit changes, the editig polygon is a RubberBand => configure it in options|digitizing|rubberband

Comment: The question is not PyQGIS related, is it?

Comment: @gcarrillo I invoke the add feature method by using pyqgis and so I expect a solution most preferrably by using pyqgis.